# How to change v-carousel scroll/slide transition speed?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a v-carousel with some images and I want the slides between the itens to be slower/smoother.

What would be an elegant way to do it?

```html
<v-carousel interval="5000" :height="window.height - 48" hide-controls hide-delimiters>
                <v-carousel-item :src="congresso">
                </v-carousel-item>
                <v-carousel-item :src="stf">
                </v-carousel-item>
                <v-carousel-item :src="tse">
                </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

Comment: What's wrong, just increase the interval value- carousel will change slide after that interval - change "5000"(5sec) to "7000" (7sec)

Comment: are you talking about the speed of image change once next has been clicked or the interval time has passed?

Comment: @depperm I'm talking about the slide transition speed. Not the interval time.

Comment: It's been 7 months and we don't have feature implemented by Vuetify. Sad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that with the help of [Vuetify’s transition helper function](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/transitions/#create-your-own) that lets you to define your own transition.

First if you did not add `variables.scss` file into your project you must do that with the help of [this link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install) from official documentation. Then you can add your own custom transition to that file. Here I used the original **fade-transition** of vuetify and only changed the transition time:

```css
/* the variables.scss file */

.new-transition {
&-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
&-enter-active, &-leave, &-leave-to {
  transition: 100ms; /* here you can define your desired time for transition */
}
&-enter, &-leave-to {
  opacity: 0
}
}
```

After that in your `.vue file` you can use `createSimpleTransition` of vuetify and register that in "mounted" hook as follow:

```html
<template>
<section>
    <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(item,i) in items"
      :key="i"
      :src="item.src"
      reverse-transition="new-transition"
      transition="new-transition"
    ></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</section>
</template>

<script>
import { createSimpleTransition } from 'vuetify/lib/components/transitions/createTransition';

export default {
    name: 'Carousel',

    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/squirrel.jpg',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        const newTransition = createSimpleTransition('new-transition');
        this.$once("hook:components", () => {
            newTransition
        })
        
    }
}
</script>
```

Now you can use **new-transition** that were defined in your carousel and the time that you has set in `variables.scss` will affect in your carousel.

Answer (score 1):

```
<b-carousel
      id="carousel-1"
      v-model="slide"
      :interval="1000"
      controls
      indicators
      background="#ababab"
      img-width="1024"
      img-height="480"
      style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
      @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
      @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
    >
```

I have just tried this and it works

interval is written like this :interval="nubmer" it has : so try to put that :

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your variables.scss file:

```
.v-window {
  &-x-transition,
  &-x-reverse-transition,
  &-y-transition,
  &-y-reverse-transition {
    &-enter-active,
    &-leave-active {
      transition: 1.1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.5, 1) !important;
    }
  }
}
```

change the first param (here 1.1s) in the transition variable to set the overall speed.

*From https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7476